# Loop within loop does not run

Tags: c, primes

This code should count the number of prime numbers based on user input. If user input is 10, then I should get 4. However, I only get 0. Why does the second loop not run?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int numprime;
    numprime = 0;
    int P=1;
    for (P; P<N; P++)
    {
        if (P%2==0)
            continue;
        int e = sqrt(P);
        for (int j=3;j<=e;j+=2)
        {
            if (P%j!=0)
            {
                numprime = numprime + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", numprime);
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code to see what values each of these variables has?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your algorithm is faulty. Try debugging your code and you will easily find the problem.

Comment: Printing out the values for `e` might help. Also, the `else {continue;}` in the 2nd loop is unnecessary.

Comment: How do you know the inner loop does not run? (Hint: It does)

Comment: If `N` is `10`, `P` loops from  `1` to `9`, only `9` triggers the inner loop but the condition `P%j!=0` is not met and `numprime` is never increased.

Comment: A tip for you: Please avoid using single letter variable names like 'P', 'e' etc. And add comments to your code. It helps in long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the second loop not run?

It does run, once, when `e` is equal to 3 (that means that this happens when `P` is equal to 9), in the case that input is 10.

Change this:

```
for (P; P<N; P++)
```

to this:

```
for (; P <= N; P++)
```

since the first part had no effect, and more importantly, you want to check all `N` numbers, so the stop condition had to be modified.

Then, you need to change this:

```
for (int j=3;j<=e;j+=2)
```

to this:

```
for(int j = 2; j <= e; j+=2)
```

in order to check for prime numbers, are suggested [here](https://sillycodes.com/prime-number-program-in-c-using-sqrt/).

Furthermore, you need to change this:

```
if (P % j != 0)
```

to this:

```
if (P % j == 0)
```

since `P` is actually a prime number when the condition is met.

Moreover, you need to get rid of this:

```
if(P % 2 == 0) continue;
```

since for example 2 is a prime number, but it meets this condition, and will not be taken into account!

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like `P` starts out as `1`, so `e` is `sqrt(1)`, which is again `1`, and `j` is `3`. Therefore, `j` is not less than or equal to `1`, and the test at the top of the inner loop fails, so the loop doesn't execute the first time through. This pattern continues for each iteration of the outer loop until P becomes large enough that `sqrt(P)` is greater than `3`, at which point the inner loop does run.

Comment: @Broman Roger that -- I was at first only looking at the initial iteration of the outer loop. Adjusted the answer above.